# Going through a list in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm having trouble with lists in neo4j. I need to go through a list and compare each element with a property of another node. I tried something like this

```
MATCH (C:Courses),(S:Student) 
WHERE
  C.courseid = "8" AND
  S.userid = FOREACH(l IN SPLIT(C.students,",")
    CREATE (C)<-[E:enrolled]-(S) 
RETURN E
```

where `C.students` is a string of values separated with ",". `FOREACH` was the only function that I found to do this, but I don't think I can use it that way. Any ideas of how I can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query should do what you intended:

```
MATCH (c:Courses)
WHERE c.courseid = '8'
MATCH (s:Student)
WHERE s.userid IN SPLIT(c.students, ',')
CREATE (c)<-[e:enrolled]-(s)
RETURN e
```

If you have a significant number of courses or students, then you should also create [indexes](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/schema/index/) for `:Courses(courseid)` and/or `:Student(userid)`.